# How to assign user roles and hide buttons from users who are not in a role, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, roles

I know it's a lot of articles about roles and authorization but I need something different and I can't find anything so far..
I'm working on a Web application built in ASP.NET, C# behind and a MySQL database connected.

So what I need is just a simple check somewhere(web.conf or Default.aspx.cs, I don't know)

```
if user "admin" (i.e inRole="admins") -> give permissions to everything
if user normalUser1 (i.e inRole = "users) -> HIDE 2 buttons
```

so they are not able to click them.

The example:
Admins can click a button Upload and Delete which access the database behind
Users can not click Upload or delete, maybe hide the button it self

If you have any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built in control within asp.net that allows for this functionality.

Check out the `<asp:LoginView>` control. This allows you to show/hide certain controls depending on if a user is authenticated, also depending on what roles you have specified.

Have a look at these links below. They describe how to use it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx#the_loginview_control

http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2010/07/28/role-based-authorization-using-loginview-control.aspx

On assigning users to Roles, you can either use the built in ASP.NET Configuration Tool within Visual Studio, or you can create your own code/UI to manage this.

Comment: Great.. the second one was exactly what I was looking for.
Thanks dude :)

Comment: Hey Tim just one more question..
It's working great but only with one button inside. When I try to add the FileUpload control and the upload button itself inside the LoginView it does not find the name of the FileUpload.. its pretty strane 
Should I consider using one more LoginView for these buttons?

Comment: This really requires another question. If you stick this in a new question, then I can answer as it would be good for a full explanation with code examples and your existing code/markup.

Comment: Okay sure. Do i do this by just starting a new question?

Comment: yeah. just start a new question and post the link here so i can access it quickly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138139/managing-user-roles-is-there-a-need-for-more-than-one-loginview-in-order-to-co
Here it is :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest idea is to place 2 admins buttons to separate `Panel` and hide it on the server side:

```
adminFunctionalityPanel.Visible = User.IsInRole("Admins");
```

Or just hide buttons itself:

```
btnDelete.Visible = btnUpload.Visible = User.IsInRole("Admins");
```

http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/role-based-authorization-cs

Comment: The second options is much easier to me... and if it is that simple - I bless you :)
Should I add this in the aspx.cs page?