# Managing user roles - is there a need for more than one LoginView in order to control more buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, roles

I created a LoginView in order to keep one button hidden from normal users, i.e not admins.
Works great but when I tried to add two more buttons - FileUploadControl and Upload button, I get an error that FileUpload1 does not exist. It definitely exists and I don't get why it complains...

Do I need another LoginView or how can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are trying to access the controls directly from the code behind as you would naturally do.

e.g.

On the .aspx page

```
<asp:FileUpload id="fileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

In the code behind

```
 string fileName = fileUploadl.FileName;
```

However, you cannot access controls directly when they are within the `LoginView`. You need to do the following. So if you had the control like this.

```
<asp:LoginView id="LoginView1" runat="server">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload1" runat="server" />
    </AnonymousTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

You can access the fileUpload1 control like this

```
 FileUpload fileUpload1 = (FileUpload) LoginView1.FindControl("fileUpload1");
```

Then you can access the `fileUpload1` properties.

Comment: Wow i didn't know that..
FileUpload fileUpload1 = (FileUpload) LoginView1.FindControl("fileUpload1");
goes in the C# code behind right? but where exactly?

Comment: Where you are trying to access the properties. Probably within your button click event.

Comment: Exactly! You just saved me :) 
Thank you soooo much Tim!